# Doesn't OpenCV require pixel pitch to calculate reprojection error?

Tags: python, opencv

When I am using a checkerboard while performing single camera calibration, I generate world coordinates using the dimension of a single box in mm. The camera only knows pixels. Where is the pixels/mm value being used, if at all? Shouldn't that be required to compute the reprojection error?

Thanks.

Comment: What stage are you asking about, calibration with checkboard or something else?

Comment: imho you give "object coordinates" of your chessboard to the calibeation function, where you can use your mm coordinates if you like to.